# Data generators for SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, generator, data-generation

I would like to receive suggestions on the data generators that are available, for SQL server. If posting a response, please provide any features that you think are important.

I have never used a application like this, so I am looking to be educated on the topic. Thank you.

(My goal is to fill a database with 10,000+ records in each table, to test an application.)

Comment: https://davutgurbuz.wordpress.com/2015/09/21/20/

Comment: If you are using .NET, Bogus provides some really nice features to do this(https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus).

Take a look at this blog post for details about how to use it: https://coderulez.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/net-core-generating-test-data/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've rolled my own data generator that generates random data conforming to regular expressions. It turned into a learning project (under development) and is available at [github](https://github.com/GoranSiska/rxrdg).

Comment: If you are using .NET, Bogus provides some really nice features to do this(https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus).

Take a look at this blog post for details about how to use it: https://coderulez.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/net-core-generating-test-data/

Answer (score 38):

I have used the [data generator](http://www.generatedata.com/#generator) in the past. May be worth a look.

#### 3rd party edit

If you do not register you can only generate 100 rows. Below you can find a sample how the interface looks today (october 2016)

[image: Example of data generator]

Comment: I wanted to add a relationship between two tables; in my case it was sufficient to use NumberRange (see the `SchoolId`-column) but if your data requires more than a simple number range it is not obvious to me how you could achieve that.

Comment: This one doesn't have DateTime options, rest is good !

Answer (score 18):

Something similar has been asked here : [Creating test data in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317/creating-test-data-in-a-database)

[Red Gate SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm) does a great job in that domain. You can customize every field of your database and using random data with seeds. And even create specific patterns using Regex expressions.

Answer (score 7):

For generating sample data, I use simple Python applications.

Considerations:

1. Simple to modify and configure.
2. A repeatable set of data that you can for performance testing and get consistent results.
3. Follow all of the DB referential integrity rules and constraints.
4. Realistic data.

The first two indicate that you want to produce script files that will load your data.  The third is tougher.  There are ways to discover the database metadata and constraints.  Looking at 3 and 4 together, you don't want simple reverse engineering -- you want something you can control to produce realistic values.

Generally, you want to build an entity model of your own so that you can be sure you have ranges and key relationships correct.

You can do this three ways.

1. Generate CSV files of data which you can load manually.  Nice repeatable test data.
2. Generate SQL scripts which you can run.  Nice repeatable data, also.
3. Use an ODBC connection to generate data directly into the database.  I actually don't like this as much, but you might.

Here's a stripped-down one-table-only version of a data generator that writes a CSV file.

```
import csv
import random

class SomeEntity( list ):
    titles = ( 'attr1', 'attr2' ) # ... for all columns
    def __init__( self ):
        self.append( random.randrange( 1, 10 ) )
        self.append( random.randrange( 100, 1000 ) )
        # ... for all columns

myData = [ SomeEntity() for i in range(10000) ]
aFile= open( 'tmp.csv', 'wb' )
dest= csv.writer( aFile )
dest.writerow( SomeEntity.titles )   
dest.writerows( myData )
aFile.close()
```

For multiple entities, you have to work out the cardinality.  Instead of generating random keys, you want to make a random selection from the other entities.  So you might have ChildEntity picking a random element from ParentEntity to assure that the FK-PK relationship was correct.

Use `random.choice(someList)` and `random.shuffle(someList)` to assure referential integrity.

Comment: Is this works with SQL Server 2000 and 2005?

Comment: This creates CSV files -- you can load the file it creates into just about any database on this earth.

Comment: Good. Cheap. Easy. I like it :)

Comment: And reasonably scalable.  You still have to model each Entity class, which requires "thinking".  But the volume of code is low, it runs fast, and you have the files.  You can use schema discovery to jump start the process.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Team System Database Edition (aka Data Dude) does this.

I have not used it for data generation yet, but 2 features sound nice:

1. Set your own seed value for the random data generator.  This allows you to prodcue the same random data more than once.
2. Point the wizard at a 'real' database and have it generate something that looks like real data.

Maybe these are standard features elsewhere?

Comment: Any specific features you find interesting? I never used it.

Answer (score 3):

I just found about that one: [Spawner](http://spawner.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I've used a tool called [Datatect](http://www.datatect.com/) for this.

Some of the things I like about this tool:

1. Uses ODBC so you can generate data into any ODBC data source. I've used this for Oracle, SQL and MS Access databases, flat files, and Excel spreadsheets.
2. Extensible via VBScript. You can write hooks at various parts of the data generation workflow to extend the abilities of the tool.
3. Referentially aware. When populating foreign key columns, pulls valid keys from parent table.

Answer (score 1):

this one is for free: http://www.sqldog.com
contains several functions like: data generator, fulltext search, create database documentation, active database connections

Answer (score 0):

I have used this before

http://sqlmanager.net/en/products/mssql/datagenerator

Its not free though.

Ref integrity checking is quite important, or your tests will be no good without correlating related data.(in most cases)