# Anonymize of a mysql database

Tags: mysql, anonymize

For testing purposes I want to anonymize our MySql database.

For example we have the next table:

```
id   |   first_name  |   last_name

54782 |  John        |   Holloway

54824 |  Glen        |   Summers

67782 |  Jessie      |   Hunter
```

We want to achieve next table after anonymization:

```
id   |   first_name  |   last_name

54782 |  Glen        |  Hunter

54824 |  Jessie      |  Holloway

67782 |  John        |   Summers
```

NOTE: there are gaps in between the id's. These id's should not be changed (but may be applied to another person).

How can I achieve this in a MySql query?

Comment: Are you ok with duplicate combinations (e.g. two Jessie Holloways)?

Comment: For this names it won't be a problem. But we also hold social security numbers which should be unique in the database. So duplicate combinations are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Because this question still has no answer...

Shifting data to other rows will help anonymize a bit but would never be my best bet. Instead I would go with this answer to erase all personal information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/260434/3090890

In your case you only would have to write one update statement per table to **really** anonymize the data and which also executes very fast.