# A good tool to populate database with dummy data?

Tags: sql-server

is there a good freeware that generates fake data for SQL Server? It would be really great if the tool generate the data according to foreign key (other constraints). Its such a repetitive task I am sure there must be a good tool for this but somehow i cant seem to find it.

Comment: similar question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157600/data-generators-for-sql-server

Comment: check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317/creating-test-data-in-a-database

Comment: Thanks for the links Amudhan.

Comment: If you are using .NET, Bogus provides some really nice features to do this(https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus).

Take a look at this blog post for details about how to use it: https://coderulez.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/net-core-generating-test-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always written my own. It rarely takes very long to write. This way I know what I'm dealing with and if it's not correct, then I can tweak as needed and re-run it.

Comment: If you are using .NET, Bogus provides some really nice features to do this(https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus).

Take a look at this blog post for details about how to use it: https://coderulez.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/net-core-generating-test-data/

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot find a free version, RedGate produce a commercial one called [SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm).

Answer (score 2):

other commercial tools. 
 1.[EMS Data Generator for SQL Server](http://sqlmanager.net/en/products/mssql/datagenerator/buy)

2.[IRI RowGen](http://www.iri.com/products/rowgen), for multiple DBs and flat files, uses Eclipse GUI

3.[Xentrix](http://www.xentrik.net/software/forsql_data_generator.html)