# Any tools to generate test data in database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, testing

I need to generate data in a database to test lucene. If anyone knows where I can get a sample database all a way to generate real life data please let me know.

I need to test millions of rows that contains real life articles.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170692/a-good-tool-to-populate-database-with-dummy-data/

Comment: Bogus provides some really nice features to do this(https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus).

Take a look at this blog post for details about how to use it: https://coderulez.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/net-core-generating-test-data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Gate has a generator too. It isn't free but they have a 14 day trial (not sure if it is a fully featured trial or has limitations).
http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm

(Yes I know that Red Gate "sponsors" one of the tags, no I am not associated with them - but have used their other products and am very happy with them)

Comment: Bogus provide some really nice features to do this(https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus).

Take a look at this blog post for details about how to use it: https://coderulez.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/net-core-generating-test-data/

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into this open source option:

http://www.generatedata.com/#about

> Ever needed custom formatted sample / test data, like, bad? Well, that's the idea of the Data Generator. It's a free, open source script written in JavaScript, PHP and MySQL that lets you quickly generate large volumes of custom data in a variety of formats for use in testing software, **populating databases**, and scoring with girls.

Answer (score 2):

There is a test data generator in Visual Studio Database Edition. I haven't used it, but I understand it's quite sophisticated and customizable. I suspect it can do what you need it to do.

Visual Studio Database Edition is free to those using Visual Studio Team Suite or Visual Studio Developer Edition. Otherwise you can use it free on a 90 (or 180) day trial basis.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot data generator

[Upscene](http://www.upscene.com/products.adg.index.php)

[SQLManager](http://sqlmanager.net/fr/products/datagenerator)

and I think many others exist.