# Is there a tool that populates SQL server with random data for testing purposes

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Data generators for SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157600/data-generators-for-sql-server)

I'm looking for a tool that populates SQL Server 2008 tables with random data for testing purposes.  Are there any such tools available?

Comment: i think you have to do it manually or insert data from other database which has the same table structure

Comment: Adventure works databses:

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587

You need to download databse, install or attach and when you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Red Gate Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/)

It automatically creates test data based on existing tables and columns.