# Generating random data sql server 2008 (firstName Surname address etc..)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-generation

Because of some testing I need to do I need to generate a database with 400000 records

I have done that with a simple

```
      "WHILE @RowCount <= @NumberRecords" etc..
```

My issue is how do I generate some sort of unique FirstName,Surname and Address.

Please dont point me to third party tool as I cannot use them .

Many thanks for your time

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to generate random data in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977388/how-to-generate-random-data-in-sql-server)

Comment: I hope this would help. Select char(CONVERT(int,26*rand())+65). 65 to 90 for the ascii A-Z. A function might help if you want consonant or vowel.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to select randomly from small table is to order by NEWID().

```
  SELECT TOP 400 *
  FROM Table1
  ORDER BY NEWID()
```

[**Read here more on efficient generation of random rows from large tables**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx)

Comment: hi thanks for your time but not use how do I generate unique surname or address from you answer.That is very genericc