# Test User Data (Fake Data)

Tags: database, testing, test-data

Where can I get, or how can I generate a large formatted collection of fake user data (names, email address, locations, etc.) that can be used for testing an application?

It can be clearly fake, this will be limited to the development server. But I'm sure anything would be better than what I could come up with.

Comment: See this SO thread: [Creating test data in a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317/creating-test-data-in-a-database#157877)

Comment: electoral role might be available?
what is it you want to test - field size large enough, data content handling, scalability? 10,000 smiths won't help the index on surname...

Comment: Try using fake data generator like [fairyland](http://codearte.github.io/fairyland>) (java)

Comment: A very constructive question which is directly related to the programming.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/16317/creating-test-data-in-a-database

Comment: This question is old but for future visitors: have a look at [randomuser.me](https://randomuser.me/). Not only is it free (for under about 10,000 users in one request) but it also provides pictures which I find extremely useful.

Comment: Please vote to reopen this question!!! http://www.convertcsv.com/generate-test-data.htm#keywords

Answer (score 74):

There are some tools built just for this.  I've used http://www.generatedata.com/ before to generate data for MySql databases.  RedGate has a nice tool to fill your SQL Server database with test data called [SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm).  The RedGate tool costs about $300, but there is a free trial.

UPDATE: 
[Faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) is now available. It is a project built on node.js, and looks pretty comprehensive.

ANOTHER UPDATE: [Mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com) is great!

If you'd like an HTTP API of fake user data, check out [Random User Generator](https://randomuser.me/)

Comment: I have made generatedata.com to work with sql server with just some basic string replacements since the basic insert format is the same.

Comment: That's awesome, Cory.  Thanks for a great tool!

Comment: Generatedata looks like a good tool, but only for US/Canadian addresses. For UK addresses it's not good unfortunately

Comment: @corymathews what specifically should be changed on the install to make it work with sqlexpress? I'm having some trouble getting rid of errors

Comment: Now there's also [databasetestdata](http://www.databasetestdata.com) which exports JSON/XML/CSV which is handy for Django fixtures etc

Comment: Looking for an API of fake users? Try https://randomuser.me

Answer (score 8):

This is a open source tool for generating various types of test data. [http://www.generatedata.com](http://www.generatedata.com/#about)

Answer (score 5):

http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/ is a good resource for creating test data with realistic looking users complete with SSN, email address, ...  They have a bulk download option too.

Comment: Please vote to re-open this question.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this list of "Funny Names" some of them are classic

http://www.ethanwiner.com/funnames.html

Comment: Please vote to re-open this question.

Answer (score 0):

Another open source test generator tool is my own http://code.google.com/p/csvtest.

Comment: It's now "404 Not Found".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an updated solution to this problem...
I wrote a test data generator project for Data Synchronisation Studio. It can generate a large dataset ranging from 1 to 100s of millions of rows of realistic testing data (lots of OFs there :D) Anyway, here is a blog post all about it. http://www.simego.com/Blog/2012/02/Test-Data-Generator-Download-for-Data-Sync