# Simplify a mysql query please

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query :

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts p
WHERE 
(
    p.userid in 
    (
        select blogid from abos where userid=11
    )
    OR p.userid = 11
) 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT null FROM posts_denied r 
    WHERE r.post_id = p.id AND r.userid = 11
)
order by p.id DESC limit 5
```

I would like to remove the "where in" clause... How can I find the best performance query syntax please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM posts p
JOIN abos a
ON p.userid = a.blogid OR p.userid = 11
LEFT JOIN posts_denied r
ON r.post_id = p.id AND r.userid = 11
WHERE (a.userid = 11 OR p.userid = 11)
  AND r.post_id IS NULL
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. Is the "distinct" clause for performances? The tables will be huge...

Comment: `DISTINCT` is in case the `JOIN`s bring up multiple matches - using `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` doesn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: And this is not possible to build it with not exists or exists? Will it have better performances?

Comment: Not sure how the performance will compare really - could you just try both and see?

Comment: Unfortunately the tables are not filled yet :-( Is there an online tool which can simulate that?...

Comment: You mean a tool to generate test data? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410653/test-user-data-fake-data#answer-410663 . I used http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bde25/14 for a bit of bare-minimum testing of this answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do with this... Thanks!