# How to Load Test wpf application that uses WCF web services to communicate?

Tags: wpf, wcf, performance-testing

I need to find out the performance of my application.This application works as follows-

- It's a WPF windows application, which requires some data to be filled by user
- On clicking Submit button, it calls WCF web services
- These services save these values in DB

Which tool would be the best for this scenario?

Comment: A "load test" of a WPF Application? Do you mean you want to simulate what happens when many users are each using one copy of the WPF application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For automated load testing you probably need two things:

1. A database server with data in it. There is a question regarding generating test data: [Creating test data in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317/creating-test-data-in-a-database)
2. You can use the [UI automation framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) to simulate user input in your WPF app.

Then setup your server and run as many clients as you want to see when it falls over.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of excellent tools. Telerik has a good tool for profiling both a .NET windows application as well as a WCF service. I've also found that JetBrains has another excellent profiler. I've used Jet Brains to profile, WCF code as well as windows applications. If you're app communicates over HTTP. Fiddler could be another good